# Ungroup/Unpivot 1 column in pandas

Tags: pandas

My data is like this

```
g1    g2   g3    value1    value2
A     X    True    1         2
A     X    False   3         4
B     Y    True    5         6
```

It was grouped by (g1, g2, g3) and then `reset_index`. What I am trying to do is to ungroup/unpivot the column `g3` so that the output looks something like this?

```
g1    g2   value1_True    value2_True   value1_False    value2_False
A     X       1                2            3               4
B     Y       5                6            0               0
```

I have tried to search online but could not find any answer for my particular case. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably want something starting with `df.set_index(["g1", "g2", "g3"]).unstack("g3", fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Make the True/False into strings, this helps later.
df.g3 = df.g3.astype(str)

# Pivot your dataframe.
df = df.pivot(index=['g1', 'g2'], columns='g3')

# flatten the multiindex columns and join like you wanted.
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().str.join('_')
print(df.reset_index().fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
  g1 g2  value1_False  value1_True  value2_False  value2_True
0  A  X           3.0          1.0           4.0          2.0
1  B  Y           0.0          5.0           0.0          6.0
```